# Finding the centre of a sphere that touches three faces of a tetrahedron.

Tags: geometry, vectors

> The tetrahedron 
>    $OABC$
>    is defined by the vectors $\mathbf a=\vec{OA}, \mathbf
>  b=\vec{OB}, \mathbf c=\vec{OC}$ with $\mathbf a\cdot(\mathbf
>  b\times\mathbf c)>0$.  A sphere  $T_r$  with radius  $r>0$ lies inside
>    the tetrahedron and intersects each of the three faces $OAB, OAC,$ and
>    $OBC$ in exactly one point. Show that the centre $P$  of $T_r$
>    satisfies $$\vec{OP}=r\frac{|\mathbf b\times \mathbf c|\mathbf
>  a+|\mathbf c\times \mathbf a|\mathbf b+|\mathbf a\times \mathbf
>  b|\mathbf c}{\mathbf a\cdot(\mathbf b\times \mathbf c)}$$.

Some useful things we've done so far:

$(1)$
The distance from a plane
$\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf n=d$
is
$d$
(assuming I've done that right).

$(2)$
The plane and the sphere
$|\mathbf x-\mathbf p|^2=r^2$
intersect at exactly one point if
$|\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf n-d|=r$.

So for the tetrahedron I considered each face as a plane through
$O$
so using the previous result
$d=0$
and so
$|\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf n|=r$
where
$\mathbf p=\vec{OP}$
where 
$\mathbf n$
could be any of the unit normals to the planes
$(\frac{(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)}{|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b|}, \frac{(\mathbf b\times\mathbf c)}{|\mathbf b\times\mathbf c|}, \frac{(\mathbf c\times\mathbf a)}{|\mathbf c\times\mathbf a|})$

(although I'm not sure I  can just say this as what we have previously shown
$((2))$
is not a necessary condition).

I can't really progress further other than just jumbling stuff around.

Help is much appreciated, thank you

(Forgive me if this has been asked before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $\vec{OP}=\alpha \mathbf a+\beta \mathbf b +\gamma \mathbf c$ and take the dot product of that with the three unit vectors. You get for instance:
$$
\vec{OP}\cdot{\mathbf a\times\mathbf b\over|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b|}=
\gamma{\mathbf c\cdot(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)\over|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b|}=r,
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
\gamma=r{|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b|\over\mathbf c\cdot(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)},
$$
and so on.

Comment: Wow that's actually quite easy. Thanks